# Is it okay to keep washing and reusing microfiber cloths for cleaning monitors?

Tags: cleaning

I've read in multiple places that microfiber cloths are one of the few materials safe enough to clean monitors without risk of scratching, so I use those whenever I need to clean the outside of any electronics.

Of course, this gets the cloth pretty dirty. I could wash them, but I know that washing/drying fabrics tends to wear them out, and I'm concerned that the microfiber might be more likely to scratch if it's worn. The cloths are nicely made so it feels wasteful to throw them out after one use.

Answer (score 2):

Empirically? Shouldn't make a difference - I just throw them in the laundry, and they haven't washed up yet. That said, if you're that worried, disposable wipes work fine, and I tend to prefer them for *really* dirty monitors.

If you believe its an issue, you might just want to hand wash them with a VERY gentle detergent and air dry. If it feels rough, swap it. Else, these things *are* designed for machine washing and a longer period of service

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of that, there isnt much logic to it. First there are huge variations in microfiber rags, some would be more abrasive on plastic (coated monitors) and should not be used on them to begin with. Some microfiber rags do not have fibers sticking upright (like terrycloth). This type of rag might more commonly be sold for that purpose. A good "polishing" quality microfiber rag works great.

Any rag used on anything would collect particulates , dust , any dirt and all. If there was going to be a problem it will exist when collected things exist (not clean). Leaving it out collecting things falling down all around. Multiple cleanings of dusty surfaces engraining in the fabrics other particals and materials.

I wash mine all the time, with one problem being washing powders and liquids, most of them even hyperalergenic and other cute names,  will leave a residue on what your washing, this residue is to make things appear cleaner , or feel soft , that residue then can cause smearing, and might also be more likely to hold dust and dirt.  I Prefer to use a non fragrance dishwashing liquid (dawn original) in small quantities (foaming) , and not to use any dryer sheets of any kind.

Can they be reused without problem?  what would change?  it is just a plastic fiber cloth item, they are not rounding off things, it is just woven (or whatever they would call that) , same sized fibers.  Yea they can be re-used, the things I outlined  would be the bigger problems.

Comment: +1 ...&  just to add; use the 'terry-towelling' type of cloth, not the smooth ones made for glass as they can be too hard on a plastic or coated screen. Wash in the cheapest generic supermarket 'bio washing powder' as it contains the least additional softeners & fabric conditioner. Micros washed with fabric conditioner are useless as they repel water. I wrote a rather pedantic cleaning method over on Ask Different - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230067/85275 Micros are also so dirt-cheap that you simply don't care when they eventually wear out... after years of use.

Comment: additionally - Tumble-dry with a 3" ball of screwed-up aluminium foil so they don't electrocute you when you take them out ;)